# Finite matrix groups as subgroups of $S_n$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, matrices, finite-groups

I have heard that all finite subgroups are isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_n$. I was thinking about examples of this. In particular I would like to know how this works for certain matrix groups.

The group $M_2(\mathbb{Z}_2)$ (group under matrix addition) has order $16$. How can I make this a subgroup of $S_n$ for some $n$? Is there some concrete map? How can one do this in general?

Comment: Any finite group indeed embeds in to $S_n$ for some $n$. But this is completely pointless. (in the sense that this fact is not really useful for any calculation) Ie a group of order 16 embeds into $S_{16}$. See http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/grouptheory/gpaction.pdf maybe.

Comment: @JackYoon: Even though it is pointless, I would still like to see how this works for $M_2(\mathbb{Z}_2)$.

Comment: The proof in the text constructs it. (theorem 1.1)

Answer (score 0):

Note that $M_2(\mathbb{Z}_2)$ is not a group under matrix multiplication. However, if we take the invertible matrices, we obtain the group $GL_2(\mathbb{Z}_2)$ of order $6$. Now it is easy to embed this group as a subgroup of $S_n$ - it is isomorphic to $S_3$. 
The additive group $M_2(\mathbb{Z}_2)\simeq (\mathbb{F}_2)^4$ embeds into $S_{16}$ by Cayley's theorem.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the group $M_2(\mathbb{Z}_2)$ under addition.

Comment: Also imbeds to $S_8$ by sending each of the four generators to $(1,2), (3,4) (5,6)$ and $(7,8)$. (Special exception as this group is abelian so it was easy to find a smaller example).